# staying lowkey and not telling everyone everything

Tags: word-meaning

> Psychology Facts tweeted just now:

Psychology says, **staying lowkey and not telling everyone everything** is a form of self-care.

Source: Twitter

Does "lowkey" here mean "quiet and relaxed"?

Comment: Try looking up **low-key**.

Comment: I had checked out dictionaries before posting the thread.  "Quiet and relaxed" is one of the definitions from there. But dictionaries have their limitations. I need native speakers to confirm this. Your reply is not helpful.

Comment: If it's mentioned in opposition to 'telling everyone everything', it may mean something like _restrained, reticent_.

Comment: I'm not sure why you doubt the dictionary!? The dictionary was written by native speakers.  Perhaps if you explained why you doubt the sense given by the dictionary in this particular case, your question could be better.

Comment: @James K: I didn't doubt it. But living in this age of information explosion, we find ourselves constantly encountering new words and new meanings and I want to be 100% certain of it.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time, OP, if you're not going to trust the dictionary. In fact, learning English is going to be almost impossible for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Staying lowkey" means keeping to yourself, not being loud, minding your own business, and reducing interactions with other people.

Comment: What source do you have for this?